# Получить список всех кафедр в которых одинаковые дисциплины и объединить в первую подходящую кафедру

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы, Кафедра (id,name) и Дисциплина (id,KafedraID) нужно получить список всех кафедр в которых одинаковые дисциплины и объединить в первую подходящую кафедру. Помогите написать SQL запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT kaf, STRING_AGG(id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) ids
              FROM dis
              GROUP BY kaf )
DELETE dis
FROM dis
JOIN cte cte1 ON dis.kaf=cte1.kaf
JOIN cte cte2 ON cte1.ids = cte2.ids AND cte1.kaf > cte2.kaf;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc727ce8b7aec5efc7379fb7da5e6d6f)

Comment: Не помню чтобы WITHIN GROUP можно было использовать в MS SQL.

Comment: хм. Действительно. Был не прав.